# How to insert array from another query as parameter in DB call FIREBASE

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build compound query in Expo react native - firestore.
I have 2 collections in firebase. First "node" is userID and second are IDs of places that had been discovered by this user. Then, I need to take this array of place IDs and pass it as parameter in 2nd query where I got name of each place stored in collection named "databaseOfPlaces". (I want to make scrollable view with names, so maybe I should add listener later on?)

My solution is not working very well. Can you help me? Is this the right way, or is there another way how to save DB call?

Thank you very much.

This is my code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("placesExploredByUsers") // default 
      .doc("mUJYkbcbK6OPrlNuEPzK")         // default
      .collection(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          alert("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push(data);
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));

      db.collection("databaseOfPlaces")
      .where('placeID','in',this.state.users)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          alert("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }
        const places = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          places.push(data);
        });
        this.setState({ places: places });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously. By the time your second query now runs, the results for the first query are not available yet.

Because of this, any code that needs the results from the first query, will need to be inside the `then()` callback of that query.

So:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("placesExploredByUsers") // default 
      .doc("mUJYkbcbK6OPrlNuEPzK")         // default
      .collection(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          alert("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push(data);
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
        db.collection("databaseOfPlaces")
        .where('placeID','in', users)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            alert("No matching documents.");
            return;
          }
          const places = [];
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            places.push(data);
          });
          this.setState({ places: places });
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for such a soon respone.But I guess I can't pass "users" as parameter as it is array of objects. Is there any way how to filter only certain field from object (in this case "name") in .where() or do I have to run for loop ? Thanks.

Comment: Okey got it, instead of doc.data() I can directly access .id :)